# Does Web API automatically convert any properties of type Object or object to JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a request from a Web API Client passing an object that has a single property of type `object`. The class is called `WebRequestObject` so in my front end controller I create a new instance of `WebRequestObject` and pass it an object of whatever type I want. For this example I will use `MyClass`.

So...

```
var reqObj = new WebRequestObject(new MyClass());
```

then

```
myWebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync('someUrl', reqObj);
```

Now on my Web API Controller Method I get the `WebRequestObject` parameter and the data is correct, but instead of being an object it's converted to a JSON string for some reason?

Is this default behavior? If so does anyone have suggestions as how to stop this or a workaround?

Edit 1: A little more infor the PostAsJsonAsync takes an interface as it's second parameter and all my models implement this interface.

Edit 2: I realize the docs say this: Sends a POST request as an asynchronous operation, with a specified value serialized as JSON. That being said I'v tested having a different type of property on my `WebRequestObject` and it gets deserialized just fine. I guess it doesn't deserialize to type of object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tested having a different type of property on my WebRequestObject
>   and it gets deserialized just fine. I guess it doesn't deserialize to
>   type of object...

This is because a `string` **is** an `object`. Since the api controller method is not being specific about how to convert the data into a CLR object, and the raw data sent over the wire is a json string, and a string is an object, it's just keeping the raw form of the request parameter.

In other words, you can always upcast a `string` to an `object`.

Comment: I understand what's going on, but I'm wondering why it doesn't go ahead and change it back to a generic object with properties, but instead keeps it as a string. This basically just adds an extra step for me having to deserialize the json myself.

Comment: Because `object` does not have any properties. If you want properties on the type, then you need something more like a `dynamic`. And if you are using JSON.NET, you can deserialize it with a single like of code: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TargetType>(jsonString)`

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing. Thanks for the help.